# Cakephp Shell Cronjob Controller Action Media Temple Server

Tags: shell, cakephp, cron, mediatemple

I'm trying to create a cron job that will send a weekly newsletter. I tried creating a shell task following what [Cakephp manual](http://book.cakephp.org/view/110/Creating-Shells-Tasks) says. Then I go to the Media Temple Cron jobs and type in the following:

`php /home/#####/domains/domain.com/html/cake/console/cake -app /home//#####//domains/domain.com/html/vendors/shells newsletter`

I created the shell task on vendors/shell folder and named it newsletter.php and here's the code for it:

```
class NewsletterShell extends Shell {

    function main() {

    $this->sendEmailTo("Newsletter","subject","email@gmail.com");


    }
}
```

The sendEmailTo is a controller function I have in my appController so all my controller have access to it.

My problem is every time the Cron Job runs I get this message:

Could not open input file: /home/#####/domains/domain.com/html/cake/console/cake

I even gave all the console files (cake.php , cake.bat etc) 0777 read write properties as well as for the vendors/shell/newsletter.php

The ##### are the site number that media temple gives you but I'm not really sure I have it correct. They show an example of a cron job like this: /home/50838/data/script-name.sh

So my questions are:

Is my cake shell task correct and is the way I'm running it as a cron job accurate?

Also does anyone know where to confirm my media temple site number so I can write that off as a possible error.

Thanks in advance,

Fabian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to `var_dump(ROOT)` or any one of the other [Core Definition Constants](http://book.cakephp.org/view/122/Core-Definition-Constants) to find your directory. Just put it in a controller method somewhere, but make sure to remove it again. Or, if you have SSH access, do `pwd` on the command line.

Other than that, when invoking the `cake` console task, the `-app` parameter is supposed to point to the `app` directory, not the `shells` directory.

---

Try to use [this script](http://book.cakephp.org/view/846/Running-Shells-as-cronjobs) to run your shell as cron job, there may be some missing shell vars.

Comment: vad_dump(Root) worked great, I tried it and got the real site number and did the new with ls- ld /home/#####/ and it gave me this:

drwxr-xr-x  9 root domain.com 9 Sep 12 05:13 /home/#####/

and for ls -l /home/#####/domains/domain.com/html/cake/console/cake

-rwxrwxrwx  1 domain.com domain.com 987 Oct 29 01:13 /home/#####/domains/domain.com/html/cake/console/cake

Comment: Ok now the cron job seems to work but it's not running what's on the main function. Here's the output I'm receiving. 

http://bin.cakephp.org/view/904014056

Comment: I get the same response even If I change the cronjob I've tried:

php /home/#####/domains/domain.com/html/cake/console/cake newsletter
php /home/#####/domains/domain.com/html/cake/console/cake newsletter top10 

top10 is a diferente function in the newsletter.php shell. 

They all give the same response: bin.cakephp.org/view/904014056

Comment: See update, I've always had success using that technique so far.

Comment: Media temple won't allow me to create a cronjob that looks like that. I tried: php /home/####/domains/domain.com/html/vendors/cakeshell newsletter top10 -console /home/####/domains/domain.com/html/cake/console/cake -app /home/####/domains/modelhousethefilm.com/html/

Comment: Also Tried: php /home/####/domains/domain.com/html/vendors/cakeshell newsletter top10 -cli /usr/bin -console /home/####/domains/domain.com/html/cake/console -app /home/#####/domains/domain.com/html/

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -l /home/#####/domains/domain.com/html/cake/console/cake
```

says what?  does the cron job run as user #####?  if not, the problem is probably permissions on /home/#####/, check them with

```
ls -ld /home/#####/
```

Comment: ls: /home/#####/: No such file or directory
ls: /home/####/domains/domain.com/html/cake/console/cake: No such file or directory

So I guess my site number is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you given the "cake" file in "cake/console" directory executable permissions as well as cake.php and cake.bat?

The cron command should be:

php /home/#####/domains/domain.com/html/cake/console/cake newsletter -app /home/#####/domains/domain.com/html/app

Comment: Yup already gave them executable rights, the problem was with the site number and how I was calling the cron job as you clearly pointed out.